# Checking into a book, music, games and topics on the new GetGlue

Tags: user-interface

[GetGlue](http://getglue.com/) recently updated their user interface and I am having problems checking into a book, music, games and topics.

How can this be done or has support for books been disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some searching I found the link to the [old Get Glue website](http://o.getglue.com)

I am not sure how long it will be available so use it while its still alive,I hope they will integrate the checking in of these items on the new version.